# Swiper-slide displays vertically instead of horizontally

Tags: javascript, php, html, css

My swiper-slide works well at first and I can scroll it horizontally, but after I used php to display my product details from my database and the swiper-slide now displays vertically instead of horizontally. And that is my problem - I want to display my swiper slide horizontally.

Answer (score 4):

Firstly, I was also facing the same error then I figure out that

```
"<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/swiper/swiper-bundle.min.css" ">
```

the above link was not included in head of the HTML.....
Please visit swiper website for the link.
I hope it will be helpful.

Answer (score 2):

By default swiper sets "direction" to "horizontal" 
make sure you have set options correctly, try the following code

```
var swiper = new Swiper('.your-swiper-container', {
   'direction': 'horizontal'
});

//Using Method on page load, this will set the direction to horizontal on page load and after slider initialization

swiper.params.direction = "horizontal"; //for horizontal
swiper.update();
```